# How to handle an exception occurring in a filter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception, action-filter

I have various filters before a URL hits an controller action.

Very few filters have a complex logic which might throw exceptions.

Now, how do I catch these exceptions ?

For eg. I have a filter which handles exception occuring in a controller method.

`[ActionFilter1]` is  a filter which handles any exception occuring in a controller method.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{

 //exception occuring here

}
```

One way is to do something like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
     try {
     //exception occuring here
     }
     catch {
     //log here
     }
    }
```

since there are `n` filters, I do not want to repeat this logic of adding `try` & `catch` to each and every filter.

In that case, how can I proceed with a single place error handling which can handle any exceptions occurring in all these filters ?

Comment: this could be helpful: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/handling-errors-effectively-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: If you don't catch it in the filter I think the next stop is in the global/app level. The problem with filter exceptions is that unless you eat it you cannot render a view because the action is effectively invalid and cant be called again without going into a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read this article. You will find the answer
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/850062/Exception-handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC-methods-explaine

Comment: Actually, the article discusses about exception handling across controllers. I am looking out for something which can handle exceptions across all controllers, action methods, filters & globally...

Comment: above attribute class you need to write this : [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)] so that it can be applicable to actions as well as controllers

Comment: Yes, it would only catch exceptions from `1actions` and `controllers`. what if an exception occuring from a `filter` or outside of actions and controllers ?

Comment: for the error inside your filter you can use try-catch ... can you specify the outside section you referring ?

Comment: I have say 20 filters. I do not want to use `try.. catch` for all those 20 filters

Comment: You can use this Handle Error attribute above all the other filters except its own filter class.

Comment: You are right. `HandleError` attribute has an order of `-1`, which when applied to a whole area or at a global level, captures issues occuring in filter context also. Great Insight. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Divya's answer/comments, here's my find:

Code snippet:

```
[Filter1, Filter2, MyErrorFilter]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //throw new Exception("Poda!");
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }

    public class Filter1 : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("filter1-action executing!!");
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("filter1-action executed!!!");
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }

    public class Filter2: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("filter2-action executing!!!");
            throw new Exception("poda!!1");
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("filter2-action executed!!!");
            base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        }
    }

    public class MyErrorFilter : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("an exception captured!!!");
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Now, the exception is occuring at `Filter2` which is being captured by `HandleErrorAttribute` (This filter has an order of -1, btw)

So, even If you have `n` filters, if any of the exceptions occur, then it is captured at the `HandleErrorAttribute` level :)

**Note[2017 Nov]:** You can register this `MyErrorFilter` at a global level so ***you need not decorate it on top of every controller*** you have.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new MyErrorFilter());
    }
}
```